# Using Third Isomorphism Theorem on Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $U \subset V \subset W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$, show that $V/U \leq W/U$ and $W/V \cong \frac{W/U}{V/U}$.

My progress is like this.

Let $U \subset V \subset W$ be vector spaces over $F$.
Define the equivalence relation ~ on $V$ such that for some $x$, $y \in V$, if $x - y \in U$, then $x$ ~ $y$.

$\rightarrow$ $V/U = \{ [v] \mid [v] = v+u \text{ for all }u \in U, v \in V \}$

$\rightarrow$ $W/U = \{ [w] \mid [w] = w+u \text{ for all }u \in U,w \in W \}$.

Obviously, $[0] = \{ 0 + u \mid u \in U \} \in V/U \subset W/U$

Let $[v_1], [v_2]$ be equivalence classes in $V/U$ and $\alpha$, $\beta \in F$.
$$[\alpha v_1] + [\beta v_2] = \{ (\alpha v_1 + u) + (\beta v_2 + u) \mid u \in U \} = \{ (\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2) + u \mid u \in U \} \in V/U$$

Therefore, $$V/U \leq W/U.$$

Then I’m stuck. At first, I suppose $T \colon W \rightarrow \frac{W/U}{V/U}$ to be a linear transformation, but I cannot figure out what would $T$ look like and how to find its kernel and its image.

Does anyone have any clue or roadmap for me to prove it?

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Until you say which $T$ you have in mind no one can help you.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think I need to edit once again. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the map
$$S: W/U \to W/V: w+ U \mapsto w+ V.$$

Then prove the following:

(1) $S$ is a well-defined linear map.

(2) $\ker(S) = V/U$.

(3) $S$ is surjective.

(4) Use the first isomorphism theorem to find the desired isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your roadmap. Now I’m proving (3). How can I show that $S$ is onto? In fact, it is, but how?

Comment: @user955961 There is not much to prove. Take an element $z \in W/V$. Hence, it is of the form $z = w+V$ for some $w \in W$. Then $S(w+U) = w+V = z.$